# Azure Functions Premium plan timeout

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

Is there a 10min max timeout for Azure Functions [Premium Plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-azure-functions-premium-plan-for-enterprise-serverless-workloads/) the same way it applies on the Consumption Plan? Is it possible to configure a greater timeout?

When working with Azure Functions on App Service Plan I can have functions with essentially any timeout by configuring the function app to "always on" and using the setting "functionTimeout" on host.json.

However this setting seems ignored in the case of the Premium Plan while the "always on" option is absent on the configuration menu.

While the Premium Plan is a great improvement I would have expected to have the option to configure the functionTimeout to more than 10min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions in a Consumption plan are limited to 10 minutes for a single execution. [**In the Premium plan, the run duration defaults to 30 minutes to prevent runaway executions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan#unbounded-run-duration). However, you can modify the host.json configuration to make this unbounded for Premium plan apps.

In preview, your duration is not guaranteed past 12 minutes and will have the best chance of running beyond 30 minutes if your app is not scaled beyond its minimum worker count.